# Is there an option in Xcode to automatically override all parent methods?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have [a strange problem with a `UILabel` subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660026) when an instance is loaded from a XIB file.

To trace the origin of the problem within the loading / init process I would like to override all `UILabel` (available/ "pubic") methods in my subclass to add some logging.

**Is there an option in Xcode to do this automatically?**

It seems that there a more than hundret potential methods and implementing them all manually would be quite cumbersome.

So I am looking for an easy way to auto generate the methods like this

```
override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
    super.addSubView(view)
    <#code#>
}

override func accessibilityIncrement() {
    super.accessibilityIncrement()
    <#code#>
}

override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {
    <#code#>
    return super.accessibilityActivate()
}

override func accessibilityElementCount() -> Int {
    <#code#>
    return super.accessibilityElementCount() -> Int
}

...
```

*I am aware that most of the methods have absolutely nothing to do with the instance init/setup but to be sure to miss nothing I would like to add logging to all available methods.*

Comment: What is the strange problem you have with the labels? I would look deeper into your subclassing before getting into any of this.

Comment: I have added a link to the question dealing with the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660026

Comment: It appears that the underlying problem is that `awakFromNib()` is not being called down the view hierarchy, which is not an uncommon problem. `UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView` and `UIView` has a number of lifecycle methods that you can override in your subclass. Before getting into anything else, try replacing `awakeFromNib()` with another method, like `updateConstraints()` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I have added logging  and break points to the `UILabel` methods which are overwritten in my subclass and `awakeFromNib()` **is** called and executed (otherwise the code would not work at all and not only fail when named colors are used...). Additionally I would propose to discuss the problem with the `UILabel` subclass in the linked question. This question here is about how/if Xcode can auto-implement parent methods.